# Remote restart from Jboss 5.1.0

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

How to do remote restart from JBoss 5.1.0? This is possible only using the JMX interface?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not possible. There is no method for this operation in the Server bean (jboss.system).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with JMX, wheter it's via `jconsole`, the `admin-console` or `JON`, all three of those in the end invoke a JMX MBean